# New line character %250A in URL: Apache throws 404 error

Tags: apache-2.2, url

This is example of the script path which causes problem:

```
http://example.com/index/index/tokenID/345%250Atest
```

If I try to visit this link on the production server I receive 404 error. If I try to visit it on local machine:

```
localhost:8080/index/index/tokenID/345%250Atest
```

everything works well.

Both servers on Apache. Production server - Cent OS, localhost - Ubuntu. It looks like there is some configuration in Apache file that I forgot to set.

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3871762/503621 - use `%0A` for \n and `%0D` for \r

Comment: Using `%250A` in a online url decoder produces bad result. Maybe try 'hashing' the 'token' first (a-Z / 0-9 chars only?) before adding/encoding to URL? Or run through script first to replace bad ones with above?

Answer (score 0):

From RFC 1738 specification (not the latest):

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
> reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
> unencoded within a URL.

[The current spec is RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-11)

Now that statement above is for unencoded characters but yours is encoded. I haven't found the similar statement.

> A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of
> digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols.  A reserved subset of
> those characters may be used to delimit syntax components within a
> URI while the remaining characters, including both the unreserved set
> and those reserved characters not acting as delimiters, define each
> component's identifying data.

Comment: Hi, Rob. I don't understand your answer. I use urlencode() function in order to pass data in URL. Result of this function contains %250A which is url encoded character (new line symbol, as I understand). Why it can be handled by one type of the servers and can not by others?

Comment: @Tamara I believe the encoded newline is %0A.  %240A decodes to %0A.

Comment: @BillThor I thought %250A decodes to %0A. Anyway if I replace %250A with %0A it still doesn't work on the production server, but works on localhost.

Comment: @Tamara You may not have the same content or same docroot on both systems.  It is strange to have /index/index in the path, although this is legal.  Having linefeeds in a filename is also strange.  You may also have permission issues.  Check the error log.